# How to add List values through Foreach

Tags: c#, wcf

I wrote the following code inside WCF Service Application:

```
public List<Presid> GetPresalesIdList(string userlogin)
{
    List<Presid> idsales = new List<Presid>();
    Presid presales = new Presid();
    string cmb = userdomain + userlogin;
    InitializeCRMService(userName, passWord, domain);

    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userlogin))
        {
            QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression("systemuser");
            string[] cols = { "businessunitid", "domainname", "systemuserid" };
            qe.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
            qe.Criteria.AddCondition("domainname", ConditionOperator.Equal, cmb);
            qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(cols);

            var guid = _service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);

            userid = ((EntityReference)guid[0].Attributes["businessunitid"]).Id;
            systemid = (Guid)guid[0].Attributes["systemuserid"];

            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("opportunity");
            string[] cols2 = { "new_presalesid", "ownerid" };
            query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
            query.Criteria.AddCondition("ownerid", ConditionOperator.Equal, systemid);
            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(cols2);
            EntityCollection preid = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
            foreach (Entity enty in preid.Entities)
            {
                presales.PresalesID = enty.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_presalesid");
                idsales.Add(presales);
            }

            return idsales;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    return idsales;
}
```

But when I test this service, the return value (`idsales`) is empty. I mean, no data has been inserted there. The question is how to add list value through foreach loop.

**EDITED**
Previously, i did't use data contract for this code, so in the List line, i write like this:

```
public List<string> GetPresalesIdList(string userlogin)
    {
        List<string> idsales = new List<string>();
        string cmb = userdomain + userlogin;
        InitializeCRMService(userName, passWord, domain);
        try {
foreach (Entity enty in preid.Entities)
                {
                    idsales.Add(enty.GetAttributeValue<String>("new_presalesid"));

                }
}
```

Those code work as expected.

After using data contract, i replace `List<String>` with `List<Presid>`

This Data Contract code:

```
[DataContract]
public class Presid
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PresalesID { get; set; }
}
```

**EDITED**

```
 string tes = string.Empty;
                foreach (Entity enty in preid.Entities)
                {
                    tes = tes + enty.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_presalesid");
                    presales.PresalesID = tes;     
                    idsales.Add(presales);

                    // idsales.Add(enty.GetAttributeValue<String>("new_presalesid"));
                }
```

By using this code, i can see that the presid.Entities has data inside. I think the problem start appear when i want to insert record from string into list one after another. Have an idea ?

Comment: You do it in precisely the way you have done it, which means that the foreach loop is not the reason your list is empty. Debug the rest of your code and see what the value of your various variables are at each step.

Comment: Check if `preid.Entities` has any values in it.

Comment: How do you test your WCF Application? How do you call the service? If is it a communication fault, in the debug is the value not empty, but in the client the value is empty.

Comment: @naro : I test by browsing it in the browser, through this link :
http://localhost:44880/Service1.svc/GetPresalesIdList/jaya

And yes, in the sources, not all records has value.

Comment: @FikriHailal did you set breakpoints in your code?

Comment: @tshoemake: Nope, above is the whole my code for Service1.Svc. Could you give me an example breakpoint. I mean where should i set breakpoint inside my code ?

Comment: foreach (Entity enty in preid.Entities) <-- this line and traverse through the loop to see if it has data.  Also break on idsales at the end to make sure its adding to your list.

Comment: @FikriHailal are you aware that you are adding same Presid object reference into the list, when going through the loop? In addition, you'll have list of same objects with exactly the same PresalesID after you eventually fix your issue with empty list...

Comment: @tshoemake: After edited my code a little, its give me a value, but just its just 1 value. The other value not stored inside the list:

`foreach (Entity enty in preid.Entities)
                    {
                        presales.PresalesID = enty.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_presalesid");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(presales.PresalesID))
                        {
                            idsales.Add(presales);
                            break;
                        }
                    }`

Comment: You need to add breakpoint where i said, then see if preid.Entities has anything in it.  If not, work backwards and see why it isnt. Make sure Entity enty has value before you enter the loop iteration.  Then just go line by line with the debugger in the loop. Debugging 101 :}

Comment: If you're not getting your data into preid.Entities your problem maybe above the loop with the _service and qe variables.

Comment: @tshoemake: But when i did't use data contract, its return value as i expected. Take a look at my question above, i have edited my question

Comment: It isn't every time the same what the service send and the client get. To test this, you can activivat the logging(MessageLogging). With this you get a *.svc file, into this the service write what he was sending. If there a list with your values: sending was not ok; if there is a empty list: the method or the return was not ok. You can analyse the response from the service with dataContract and without.

Comment: @tshoemake: Hii, i m sure that preid.entities has data. So i modified my code this: `string tes = string.Empty;
                    foreach (Entity enty in preid.Entities)
                    {
                        tes = tes + enty.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_presalesid");
                        presales.PresalesID = tes;     
                        idsales.Add(presales);
                        
                        // idsales.Add(enty.GetAttributeValue<String>("new_presalesid"));
                    }`

Comment: The string tes, returning shows me that there are bunch of presalesID. my presales.PresalesID is string. I though that i need to change into list, but when i change into list, its shows me another error.

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for my problem. I need to instaniate my class inside the loop. Just add `presales = new Presid();` within foreach.

**The reason :**

Class is an object. When you instantiate a new object will be created. When you instantiate outside foreach loop it will create one object, and in the loop is assigned to same object till the loop ends. This means that when a loop executes your previous value will be cleared. And in your list you are adding the same object again and again, but the value inside the object will be overwritten each time.
But when you instantiate inside the loop , new objects will be created for each looping and hence you are assigning your value to this new object. This object is added to your list. So when you access the list it will contain the number of objects of your class which is equal to the count of your loop and each object contains separate value that you assigned in your loop.